# Bluehost - Cronjob setting changes without my intervention

Tags: php, cron, shared-hosting, bluehost

I have a shared hosting account on Bluehost.
I have set a cron job (of opening a php file on my site) on cPanel that runs every 1 min. It works well initially but when I'm back after a day, I see that the cron job frequency has been changed to something else (every 22 mins, or every 23 mins). I am 100% sure that no one but me and bluehost staff has access to my settings. They claim that they never change a user's settings so this has to be some automated change by linux. Have you ever experienced something like this? What could the reason be?

This is really weird and annoying cause it disrupts my website functionality

Comment: Create another cron job which writes a date to a text file every min, if it is indeed only fired every 23 mins then you can definitely say something is up with the hosting. Contact the support again with evidence and say if you don't look into it then i'll change host. Its trivial for them to debug this.

Comment: It's fired every minute initially. But the settings are changed to every 23 minutes overnight. It's not a hidden change. In the Cronjob settings on cPanel, it's changed to every 23 min.

Comment: Then put it back to every min, how many times has it *switched*?

Comment: twice. It was not a random error. seems like a systematic problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future bluehost shared hosting customers:

This is their response:

> I spoke to engineers and it is the root server causing time reset.
>   There is no way to fix it on shared server about synch to the server
>   time.

So basically if you have shared hosting, you can't have cron jobs. At least not the ones that run every 1 min.

Comment: FYI: there are dozens of sites that will hit your script on a schedule ie https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: Yes. I figured that out. It was just dishonest of bluehost not to be straightforward about this.

Comment: well shared hosts are not worth the money any-more, you can get dedicated hosting for the same amount of money